# Добавление <meta name=“robots” content=“noindex,follow”> к ссылкам

Tags: html

Есть задача добавить к ссылкам тег `<meta name=“robots” content=“noindex,follow”>`.
Правильно ли поставлена задача?
По идее для ссылок нужно ставить атрибут `rel="nofollow"`
Разве если добавить вышеприведённый тег `meta` в ссылку `<a>`, он также будет работать?
Возможно эту задачу кто-то не правильно поставил, некомпетентное лицо.
Как можно решить другим способом?

Comment: Нет, не будет. Это не задача, а непонятно что

Comment: @andreymal, а подскажите, как правильно нужно поставить к ссылкам эти атрибуты: `noindex,follow` ?

Comment: или этот тег `meta` по идее нужно ставить для всей страницы?

Comment: Вы для начала определитесь — зачем вам вообще нужно ставить что-то куда-то?

Comment: @andreymal, мне поставили эту задачу, но я точно не знаю, правильно ли она поставлена

Comment: Семь перпендикулярных красных линий. Отвечаете «задача некорректна» и уходите до получения корректной задачи :)

Comment: @andreymal, я уже спрашивал, как тогда добавить эти атрибуты к ссылке? `noindex,follow`

Comment: Эти атрибуты к ссылке добавлять бессмысленно, они ничего не будут делать

Comment: Добавлять его надо на страницу. Добавляется, чтобы в выдаче поисковых систем не было индексных страниц - например, списка материалов сайта

Comment: @andreymal, разве вам данный атрибут новый `rel="nofollow"`? поисковая система не будет следовать по ссылке

Comment: Бред какой-то, зачем к ссылкам добавлять meta? В самом meta  указано: запрещает индексировать текущую страницу и дает возможность работы по ссылкам на данной странице...

Comment: @word добавлять `nofollow` смысл есть, он для ссылок работает. Добавлять `noindex,follow` смысла нет, они для ссылок ничего не значат

Answer (score 3):

Вы всё верно написали, для ссылок ставится `rel="nofollow"`.

`<meta name=“robots” content=“noindex,follow”>` же записывается в начало файла обычно в `head` блок.

И это не одно и тоже.

`rel="nofollow"` означает что по данной ссылке роботу не надо переходить, возможно он будет делать переход, но такой переход в расчёте релевантности страниц участвовать не будет.

В то время как `<meta name=“robots” content=“noindex,follow”>` означает что всю страницу не надо индексировать (то есть содержание страницы в индекс не попадёт), но при этом сама страница будет обойдена роботом и по ссылкам будет идти переход со всеми вытекающими последствиями.
Заметим что написано *follow* а не *nofollow*.